# Python: How to split text into multidimensional array

Tags: python, string, multidimensional-array

I'm grabbing data from a web-page and finally have 5 strings which look like this:

```
  charts[1]['min']    = [['Mi',5.6],['Do',2.9],['Fr',1.7],['Sa',3.7],['So',2.9],['Mo',4.1],['Di',4]];
  charts[1]['mittel'] = [['Mi',6.2],['Do',5.4],['Fr',3.9],['Sa',4.5],['So',4.7],['Mo',5.4],['Di',4.6]];
  charts[1]['max']    = [['Mi',7.2],['Do',8.8],['Fr',5.9],['Sa',5.5],['So',6.8],['Mo',6.6],['Di',5.8]];
  charts[2]['line']   = [['Mi',59],['Do',69],['Fr',72],['Sa',65],['So',66],['Mo',65],['Di',76]];
  charts[3]['line']   = [['Mi',5],['Do',4],['Fr',0],['Sa',5],['So',0],['Mo',5],['Di',0]];
```

Obviously I would need an array containing only the right part. Data is always a day (in German) and a number. New to Python I look for an easy solution. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear the data structure. Each whole row is a string? `str1 = "charts...   = ..."`?

Comment: only the part after the = is the data

Comment: but it already looks like it is a 2d array

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh. Yes but it seems to be a fragment of a javascript?

Comment: @Corralien why would you assume so?

Comment: yes, unfortunately its a heating device without proper Rest API. So I have to grab the data from an HTML file which contains javascript.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh. Because the OP is *grabbing data from a web-page*

Comment: @Corralien There's python packages to do that for you, no?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh. Yes but the problem here is not to extract data because OP already did it but to convert this string into a python data structure.

Comment: yes, I used BeautifulSoup but it looks like, you cannot parse scripts with that. So did it differently to get the data into a text array but that one I need to translate as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import ast

str1 = "charts[1]['min']    = [['Mi',5.6],['Do',2.9],['Fr',1.7],['Sa',3.7],['So',2.9],['Mo',4.1],['Di',4]];"

arr1 = ast.literal_eval(str1.split('=')[1].strip()[:-1])
print(arr1)

# Output:
[['Mi', 5.6],
 ['Do', 2.9],
 ['Fr', 1.7],
 ['Sa', 3.7],
 ['So', 2.9],
 ['Mo', 4.1],
 ['Di', 4]]
```